# Initialize Azure Cosmos DB connection and upsert data

Tags: f#, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to F#, and want to find any references on how to create a functionApp using F# and upsert data into cosmos DB

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this [example](http://%20https://github.com/Dzoukr/CosmoStore/blob/2e0ef27318ffe7e9d226be8237a946174bd8e1f4/src/CosmoStore.CosmosDb/CosmosDb.fs) to get an idea

```
let private createCollection (dbUri:Uri) (throughput:int) (client:DocumentClient) =
    let collection = DocumentCollection( Id = collectionName)

    // always use partition key
    collection.PartitionKey.Paths.Add(sprintf "/%s" partitionKey)

    // unique keys
    let streamPath = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string>()
    streamPath.Add("/streamId")
    streamPath.Add("/position")
    let keys = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<UniqueKey>()
    keys.Add(UniqueKey( Paths = streamPath))
    collection.UniqueKeyPolicy <- UniqueKeyPolicy(UniqueKeys = keys)

    // throughput
    let throughput = throughput |> Throughput.correct
    let ro = new RequestOptions()
    ro.OfferThroughput <- Nullable<int>(throughput)

    task {
        let! _ = client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(dbUri, collection, ro)
        return ()
    }
```